# printf error printing a char in masm32

Tags: assembly, printf, scanf, masm, masm32

This is the first time that i write here... I try to explain my problem!
I wrote this code in masm32

```
.586
.model flat
.data

mess db "digita un carattere    ",0
res db "x = %c",10,0

.data?
salva db ?

.code
extern _printf:proc
extern _scanf:proc

_funzione proc
;pre
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push ebx
push edi
push esi

mov eax, offset mess
push eax
call _printf ;puting out the message
mov eax, offset salva
push eax
mov eax, offset res
push eax
call _scanf ;taking the char and saving it in "salva"
add esp,12
xor eax,eax
mov eax,offset salva
push eax
mov eax, offset res
push eax
call _printf ;printing the char
add esp,8

;post
pop esi
pop edi
pop ebx
pop ebp

ret
_funzione endp
end
```

When i compile it the output is:

[image: output]

I dont understand why _printf doesnt print the char ('y') that _scanf had read...
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format strings of `printf` and `scanf`are **very** different. The [`scanf` format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kwwtf9ch.aspx) controls **only** the input, `scanf` does **not** output something (just echo the inputted character). `scanf` will produce nothing but an error with `res db "x = %c",10,0`. Add a line  `scanf_res db "%c",0` and change `mov eax, offset res` to `mov eax, offset scanf_res`.

The [`printf` format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) `res db "x = %c",10,0` expects a direct value to be pushed, not an offset of a string. Change `mov eax,offset salva` to `mov al, salva`.

```
.586
.model flat
.data

mess db "digita un carattere    ",0
scanf_res db "%c",0
res db "x = %c",10,0

.data?
salva db ?

.code
extern _printf:proc
extern _scanf:proc
extern _fflush:proc

_funzione proc
;pre
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push ebx
push edi
push esi

mov eax, offset mess
push eax
call _printf ;puting out the message
mov eax, offset salva
push eax
mov eax, offset scanf_res
push eax
call _scanf ;taking the char and saving it in "salva"
add esp,12

xor eax,eax
mov al, salva
push eax
mov eax, offset res
push eax
call _printf ;printing the char
add esp,8

;post
pop esi
pop edi
pop ebx
pop ebp

ret
_funzione endp
end
```